# Where's girdled look out, above coast, in Oregon?

Tags: discussion

> This post is hidden. It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 1 hour ago by Community♦.

I posted four questions yesterday Apr 21 2020 on video uploaded May 22 2015, so no use commenting, because Jessica Zraly probably doesn't check any more since all this time.  I got lots of downvotes. I'm sad. Why?

Community deleted https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156829 but why? "spam or offensive content"!??!?!?  I emailed Jessica Zraly video maker four times since 2019, but got no reply. I still want know locations, so asked here. I no way affiliated with any video maker.

Don't worry. I not travelling in pandemic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was marked as spam by one or more users and when I had a look I followed their lead and also flagged it. Your post has shown me it was a wrong decision, so I have undeleted and unlocked it.

Best if you now edit the question and make clear you are not having anything to do with the rights owner. The normal ways is to add something like: "I am not connected to this site".
And to add something like you did here, 'I am researching these locations so in the future I can visit them."

Sorry for the wrong reporting.

Comment: Thanks. No problem. Too bad not all moderators are nice and humble as you!